# How to replace section of basement insulation

Tags: insulation, basement

I had a leaky basement window and need to replace some of the insulation.  The basement is insulated with rock wool in a bag attached to the top half of the foundation.  No insulation until about 3-4 feet from the floor.  It's my understanding that the bag is permiable on the foundation side and so it could have gotten wet and will need to be replaced.  If I replace a section of insulation, should I use rigid foam board all the way to the ground or leave the bottom half uninsulated as before?

The house is in Ottawa, Canada and -30C happens every year.

Edit: more info, I got adventurous and started pulling away the insulation on another side of the house.  I've heard this method called "wall bag".  Turns out, its just vapour barrier attached to the wall holding up insulation.  But my question remains the same: I'll have to remove a portion of insulation, what's the best way to replace it?  More rock wool and vapour barrier or seal off either side of the good insulation and use rigid foam board.

[image: example of insulation]

Comment: Insulation should go down to at least frost level or a bit below.  Below frost level, insulation is less needed.  Insulation installed in bags is a new one to me.  Maybe post a picture.

Comment: I think foam board needs to be behind a fire block, like drywall.  Nasty stuff when burning.

Comment: Agreed, the section I'm replacing is behind drywall in the finished part of the basement.  Thanks for the warning not to take the opportunity to do more than I need